# using custom font with more than 255 symbols

Tags: qgis

I would like to use a font for the styling of a layer.

The font contains more than 255 characters. QGIS seems to read only the first 255 characters of the font, right? At least, I can only see the character from 1 to 255 in the styling-dialog.

How can I use one of the other characters of the font?

Comment: Where did you get the font? ASCII fonts may contain up to 255 characters. How many characters does your font contain?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure where you're seeing that limit.

In QGIS 2.18 at least, you have access to all Unicode characters which your font supports. They should also appear in the selection of the **Font Marker** style.

Here's an example, zoomed in so you can see. I've got a layer of around 30000 grid squares, each with a unique id (field `gid`).

If I use labels with this expression...

```
char("gid")
```

you can see a lot of unicode characters...

[image]

Here, I used the font '[unifont](http://unifoundry.com/unifont.html)'. It's a bitmap font, which is why it's blocky, but also got it work with other traditional fonts which have good unicode coverage.

Your mileage will vary according to the font you're using; some fonts (particularly decorative ones) may be limited to ascii/latin characters, as MaryBeth pointed out.

Comment: tx. that pointed me in the right direction!